# WebView clearHistory() on Webview canGoback() functionality?

Tags: java, android, webview

1. I'm trying to use the history as a check to exit the application. The home button reloads the page to google.com, but still retains page history even after I call .clearHistory().
2. Here is the code for the Menu handling / selections:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle item selection
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.Home:
         mWebview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
         mWebview.clearHistory();
         return true;
       case R.id.About:
         Toast.makeText(this, "TEXT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return true;
       default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Here is the code for the Exit function:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
     if (mWebview.canGoBack()) {
       mWebview.goBack();
     }
     else {
       super.onBackPressed();
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Onpbm7esvsM) you need to call clearHistory when the page finished loading:

> It appears that the history  clears everything before the current page
>   so if your browser is at  page "A", you clear history and navigate to
>   page "B" your history will  be "A" "B", not just "B", but if you clear
>   history when "B" finishes  loading you will have only "B"

So instead of calling `clearHistory` right after `loadUrl`, you should envoke it from `onPageFinished` or `onProcessChanged`.